# reading csv file enclosed in double quote but with newline

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have `csv` with newline in column. Following is my **example:**

```
"A","B","C"
1,"This is csv with 
newline","This is another column"
"This is newline
and another line","apple","cat"
```

I can read the file in spark but the newline inside the column is treated as  a separate line.

How can I ready this as a csv with text enclosed inside double quote.

I read file using both apache csv plugin and apache only.

```
alarms = sc.textFile("D:\Dataset\oneday\oneday.csv")
```

This gives me RDD :

```
**example.take(5)**

[u'A,B,C', u'1,"This is csv with ', u'newline",This is another column', u'"This is newline', u'and another line",apple,cat']
```

*Spark Version : 1.4*

Comment: `line.replace('/n','') if line.count('"')%2==1 and '"\n' not in line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create dataframe from csv with newline and quoted by double quote without reinventing wheel then use spark-csv and common-csv library:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
df = sqlContext.load(header="true",source="com.databricks.spark.csv", path = "hdfs://analytics.com.np:8020/hdp/badcsv.csv")
```

Comment: CSV parser from commons will fail on newline, won't it? Did you mean univocity?

Comment: @zero323 you need to load spark-csv else it will fail if you use common-csv.

Comment: It is not what I mean. `commons` parser as far as I remember doesn't handle multiline records. `univocity` does. Both with `spark-csv` although this is more or less deprecated in 2.0+

Comment: @zero323 I am using spark 1.4. Yes, I could not get it done with *commons*.  whose 2.0+ version are you referring to? Is spark-csv depricated? https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv . Also, I could not find if it is depricated ! Is there any performance penalty using this one?

Comment: Spark 2.0+. There is no penalty it simply provides csv support in core libraries.

Comment: Great! Is spark 2.0 released? I only find 1.6.2 and 2.0 as preview.

Comment: Released? Not yet. But it is usable although there are some regressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117536/discussion-between-kinkajou-and-zero323).

Answer (score 2):

The csv module from the standard python library does it out of the box:

```
>>> txt = '''"A","B","C"
1,"This is csv with 
newline","This is another column"
"This is newline
and another line","apple","cat"'''
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> with io.BytesIO(txt) as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    for row in rd:
        print row


['A', 'B', 'C']
['1', 'This is csv with \nnewline', 'This is another column']
['This is newline\nand another line', 'apple', 'cat']
```

This can be used (with a significant performance penalty over `textFile`) with `binaryFiles`:

```
>>> (sc.binaryFiles(path)
        .values()
        .flatMap(lambda x: csv.reader(io.BytesIO(x))))
```

Comment: @zero323: Thank you for improving my answer. I know well the csv module, by I cannot say the same for spark...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import anything. The solution proposed below creates a second file just for demonstration purposes. You can read the line after you modify it without writing it anywhere.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\evkouni\Desktop\test_in.csv', 'r') as fin:
    with open(r'C:\Users\evkouni\Desktop\test_out.csv', 'w') as fout:
        cont = fin.readlines()
        for line in cont[:-1]:
            if line.count('"') % 2 == 1 and '"\n' not in line:
                line = line.replace('\n', '')
            fout.write(line)

#DEMO

#test_in.csv
#------------
#"A";"B";"C"
#1;"This is csv with 
#newline";"This is another column"
#"This is newline

#test_out.csv
#------------
#"A";"B";"C"
#1;"This is csv with newline";"This is another column"
#"This is newline
```

If there is something that's not clear to you, please let me know.

Comment: While it is a good answer in general it doesn't really address particular context.

Comment: @zero323 what does that even mean?

Comment: @zero323 OP didn't say anything about him having problems reading csvs in spark. His problem were new line characters inside the column entries. I still don't get your point although i am not familiar with spark.

Comment: How would you use in Spark? In particular you have to work with distributed data and not iterable data structures. It is possible to adjust in a similar way that the code written by @SergeBallesta but it is far from being a valid solution.

Comment: @zero323 Just so that we stop chasing our tail.. Can you quote OP on what you are saying?

Comment: OK, so make it simple. We can both agree that OP is using Apache Spark, right? Spark reads data using Hadoop input formats and output is non-iterable structure (RDD). In particular it is using `textFile` which splits data on newline. Resulting object doesn't provide any trivial and efficient way to "look around" and doesn't guarantee that lines from a single file will be processed on a single machine. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @zero323 So the answer could be better. Fair enough.. Like i said, i do not know what spark is or does nor am i interested in going through the documentation just to answer how to deal with newlines within quotes. Feel free to edit the answer or to post one of your own. + If you notice, i just added a comment on OP's post with my suggested solution almost 45min before writing the answer myself.